# Are RichFaces 3.3.3 and JSF 2.1 going to work fine together?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, migration, richfaces

Currently I'm using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3.3 and they work fine. But am I going to have to update my current RichFaces version up to 4.x and make the changes, coprresponding to the migration guide if I decide to update my JSF version up to 2.1.29. I mean are there components which are not going to work appropriate or ever work at the JSF 2.1.29 + RichFaces 4.x(4.5.2 in particularly) combination. I mean components like `a4j:keepAlive` which I think should be replaced with something else.

Comment: Did you really read the RichFaces migration guide? Just click the link "a4j components" in there and then lookup how to migrate "a4j:keepAlive". It's answered very clearly in there.

Answer (score 1):

Basically they are going together but with some limitations, because RichFaces 3.3.3 does not support some JSF 2 functionalities like built-in facelets (VDL), Bean Validation (JSR-303), JSF 2 afax functionality, ... see [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20?_sscc=t).

But there are some workarounds to get over the limitations...

The problems you will depends strongly on the used Richfaces Components in your project.

If you want to use JSF 2 (2.0, 2.1, 2.2) and its benefit, I would consider also updating to RichFaces 4 (4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5) in order to get all the benefits from JSF 2. You need to investigate time for both solutions. But if you go with RichFaces 4, future changes will be more efficient I think.

**If you decide to stay on Richfaces 3.3, I would consider update the version to 3.3.4 which consists of a security patch applied to the 3.3.3.Final release and which introduces basic JSF 2 support to the 3.3.X branch.**

Comment: Well... hope you did not at the time, since it has gone belly-up. All that effort would have been for nought. https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesEnd-Of-LifeQuestionsAnswers